# Facebook Long Term access token Expires:Never

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I receive this error when I use a long term access token.
`Uncaught OAuthException: An unknown error has occurred.`

The strange thing is that when I run it through the [Debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token), I get an expiration date of never on the long term token. Instead of the 60 days..

When I original created the key it ready 60days and then at some point switched over to Never.

Everything works if I use the short term key but as soon as I convert it to a long term key I get the erros. Long Term code below.
`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?

    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN`

Any ideas?
Thanks

**Update**

I solved the issue I was having.(something unrelated) Anyways my key still reads that it never expires. I was of the understanding that the longest you could have an access key was 60 days.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the duration:

Did you obtain your tokens via the /accounts connection?

> By using a long-lived user access token, querying the [User ID]/accounts endpoint will now provide page access tokens that do not expire for pages that a user manages. This will also apply when querying with a non-expiring user access token obtained through the deprecated offline_access permission.

[developers.facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/)